# coffeescript for in when vs underscore filter

Tags: coffeescript, underscore.js, filtering, list-comprehension

**Case 1:**

I would have thought these two lines of code would have produced identical results but they don't.

```
readies = _.filter sections, (section) -> section.ready()
```

vs

```
readies = section for section in sections when section.ready()
```

**Case 2:**

These two lines of code **do** produce identical results (the only difference being the parentheses)

```
readies = _.filter sections, (section) -> section.ready()
```

and

```
readies = (section for section in sections when section.ready())
```

**Case 3:**

As a counterpoint to the above, why, given the above, do the following lines produce equivalent results?

```
bobs = _.filter sections, (section) -> section.name is "bob"
```

and

```
bobs = section for section in sections when section.name is "bob"
```

Does the call to a method in **case 1** prevent the `when` clause from working as expected, and, if so, why?

Why are the parentheses in **case 2** required for it to work but not in **case 3**?

Comment: Are you sure about case three? They produce [the same JavaScript structure](http://coffeescript.org/#try:x%20%3D%20s%20for%20s%20in%20ss%20when%20s.m()%0Ax%20%3D%20s%20for%20s%20in%20ss%20when%20s.p%20is%20's'%0A) for me. Can you supply running examples on jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: Case 1 and Case 3 produce identical javascript with `section.ready()` replaced with `section.name==="bob"`  So the question is, what is `section.ready()` doing?  Case 2 produces completely different javascript which more closely aligns with the `_.filter` method, where it builds an array based on the object matching the predicate.  Case 1 and 3 will just return a single object, while case 2 and the `_.filter` method return arrays.

Comment: interesting. In case 1 the list-comprehension sans parentheses produces the equiv to `_.find …` - http://coffeescript.org/#try:x%20%3D%20s%20for%20s%20in%20ss%20when%20s.m()%0Ax%20%3D%20s%20for%20s%20in%20ss%20when%20s.p%20is%20's'%0A shows the difference. In case 3 the results are **not** equivalent. Mia Culpa

Comment: Right. Case 3 is case 1 all over again. The difference between **1** and **2** is just simple precedence: assignment binds tighter than a loop expression so you have to toss in parentheses to get the loop evaluated before the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are important in comprehensions and this is for reason. Consider function call instead of assignment:

```
foo (section for section in sections when section.ready())
```

vs.

```
foo section for section in sections when section.ready()
```

In the first case you put all ready sections together and give them as argument to the `foo`.
In the second case you call `foo` on each ready section individually.

The same is for the third case: you need parentheses to get list of all sections named `"bob"`. But if you drop parentheses, assignment will be executed for each `"bob"` in sections. And you will get just single `"bob"` in your `bob` variable (`undefined` if there are none of them and the last one if there are many).